# OpenGL ES 2.0 Specular light generates black border

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, glsl, specular

I've been working on light mechanics for an app and got the diffuse light (ambient and directional) working just fine, but the specular light creates some weird effects. As if it nullifies the diffuse light in a strip around it.

Here is the specular light calculation.

```
vec3 directionToEye = normalize(u_eyePos - position);
vec3 reflectDirection = normalize(reflect(direction, normal));

float specularFactor = dot(directionToEye, reflectDirection);
specularFactor = pow(specularFactor, u_specularExponent);

if(specularFactor > 0.0){
    specularColor = vec4(base.color, 1.0) * u_specularIntensity * specularFactor;
}
```

And then the overall light calculation function returns this.

```
return diffuseColor + specularColor;
```

And in the main() function I just multiply them all together.

```
gl_FragColor = baseColor * textureColor * returnedValueOfTheLightCalcFunction;
```

They are all vec4 values.

Here's are the screenshots WITHOUT(1.) and WITH(2.) the specular light on:

[image: one]
[image: two]

EDIT: The problem has been fixed by putting the pow function inside the if statement. I essentially forgot I have to be checking whether the dot product is > 0, not the pow function. Here is the updated code.

```
diffuseColor = vec4(base.color, 1.0) * base.intensity * diffuseFactor;

vec3 directionToEye = normalize(u_eyePos - position);
vec3 reflectDirection = normalize(reflect(direction, normal));

float specularFactor = dot(directionToEye, reflectDirection);

if(specularFactor > 0.0){
    specularColor = vec4(base.color, 1.0) * u_specularIntensity * pow(specularFactor, u_specularExponent);
}
```

Comment: The texture co-ordinates are completely different between your two screenshots, not just the lighting, so there's certainly something else going on, in the code you haven't posted. Please reduce your code to a minimal example, and then post the whole example.

Comment: The reason they're different is because the mesh is rotating, so sorry about that confusion.

Comment: Even without seeing the rest of code, the most likely cause of this symptom is that your vectors are going wrong somewhere such that `dot(directionToEye, reflectDirection)` ends up negative. You can test the hypothesis by clamping `specularFactor` to the range [0.0,1.0], and if that removes the black, track back to find out which vector is wrong.

Comment: You are right, clamping it removes the black. Thank you for the help, I will now try to backtrack the bug.

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. Are you initializing specularColor to zero anywhere? If you are, you haven't posted it.
2. The first input to the pow function MUST be >= 0, otherwise you will get undefined behaviour. (see https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf section 8.2)

Comment: I did initialize it to zero, sorry for not posting that part. And it turns out that the pow function was the problem, so I just moved the pow function inside the if statement that checks whether the dot product is > than 0.